# El valor especificado tiene caracteres de encabezado HTTP no válidos. Nombre del parámetro: name

Tags: c#, webservice, rest, wcf

Lenguaje de programación C#.

Al ejecutar un servicio de la siguiente forma:

```
string sSoapResponse;

string url = "http://MiUrl/clientes/comerciales.dll?Handler=Default";

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

var soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();

soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(requestXML);

using (var stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
}

using (var respuesta = httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (var rd = new StreamReader(respuesta.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        sSoapResponse = rd.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

La respuesta fue:

> ERROR: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server
>   Error.  STATUS: ProtocolError  Status Code : InternalServerError 
>   Status Description : Internal Server Error

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Server Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<H1>Server Error</H1>
<P>SOAP request did not provide SOAPACTION header.</body>
</html>
```

Entiendo que debo agregar algo como esto:
`httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAP:Action", "ProcesarRequest");`

Que al incluirlo arroja esto:

> El valor especificado tiene caracteres de encabezado HTTP no válidos.
>   Nombre del parámetro: name

¿Cómo hago para incluir el SOAPACTION?

La url del servicio es provista por un tercero, yo debo consumirlo, este servicio no expone el wsdl por razones de seguridad.

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos

Comment: una url http://MiUrl/clientes/comerciales.dll que termina con .dll no es valida, eso no es un servicio, valida la url porque no es correcta

Comment: Si, si es válida, desde SOAPUI puedo invocar el servicio, y responde sin problemas.

Comment: en que lenguaje desarrollado el servicio? porque es la primera vez que veo una url con extension .dll, si fuera un WCF la extension deberia ser .svc

Comment: ahh ya entiendo es un handler, con lo cual configuras la extension y le has puesto dll, uno peor y mas confusa no tenia, a los handler se le suele poner .ashx, aunque entiendo seguro estas creando un Http handler en lugar de un Generic handler. Entonces si se trata de un handler que tiene que ver wcf, rest o webservice porque los handlers no tiene ninguna relacion

Comment: Leandro, el servicio es de un tercero, yo debo consumirlo tal cual fue desarrollado por el cliente.

Comment: ok pero debes validar con el cliente que es lo que creo, porque no es wcf y mucho menos rest si se trata de un handler, se debe partir de una buena base de conocimiento que se quiere invocar para hacerlo correctamente porque las tecnicas cambian

Comment: este cliente no tiene ninguna documentacion sobre el servicio? si usas postman puedes invocar correctamente? necesitas definir algun header en la invocacion?

Answer (score 0):

En el SOAPUI hay un tab que tiene definido el SOAPAction. El tab se llama RAW, se encuentra al lado del tab XML, estos tab están: en el extremo izquierdo de la ventana de entrada de los parámetros y en el extremo derecho en la ventana de salida. Allí hay información acerca de como se consume el servicio.

La instrucción es: SOAPAction sin los ":", y el SoapAction definido va entre comillas.

```
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"ProcesarRequest\"");
```